# Pass Variable in awk and match it with $1

Tags: unix, awk

My requirement is to split a file based on the first field.
My file looks something like this :

```
aaa|12345
bbb|45679
aaa|334564
ccc|qewqw
```

Now my awk command works just fine and splits the file with respect to the first field value.

```
awk -F\| '{f=($1); print $2 > f}' /myfile
```

Result : File name aaa has the below rows :

```
12345
334564
```

Now , I want to make it input driven , that is from a script i will enter the value `aaa` to this awk command and it will match with `$1` and create the file like above. I tried with awk -v to take the value as input, but its not working the way I want it to.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will this answer your need?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script

Comment: What "no working" means? Can you show code and error message?

Comment: I tried these options , but the things is it's not doing the matching correctly . I mean if I pass a value 'v' the entire file content is saved under value 'v' which I don't want. @James Brown

Comment: There is no way to tell you what you're doing wrong, if you're not showing the code.

Comment: this is what I am try to do : awk -v "var=$input_value" -F\| '{f=($var); print $2 > f}' /myfile . But here I am not sure of how to compare the $1 value with var as a result the entire file content is moved to var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?:

```
$ awk -v f=aaa -F\| 'f==$1{print $2 > f}' file
$ ls
aaa file
$ cat aaa
12345
334564
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -v f=aaa -F\| '     # set input field separator and var f="aaa"
f==$1 {                   # if f ie. "aaa" equals to first field value
    print $2 > f          # write second field value to file f ie. "aaa"
}' file
```

Comment: can you please explain, where $1 and aaa are compared and only values corresponding to $1=aaa are retrieved in this code, sorry but I am new to this, so may be I am asking basic questions.

Comment: `-v f=aaa` passes string `aaa` to variable `f`. `$1~f` is the matching, now that I had my morning coffee I see that it's faulty, you should use `f==$1`, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v var=$input_value -F\| '{print $2 > var}' myfile
```

In your code in comments the problem is with `f=($var)`. I think you wanted `f=var`.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file | awk -v inp=aaa -F\| '$1 ~ inp { print $2 > inp }'
```